# How to pass data from one file to other in python?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, python-3.x, vue.js

My html code is (ser.html)

```
<div>
<a v-bind:href="'ser/'+post.name">
{{post.name}}</a>
</div>
```

I need to pass post.name from this file to other ie.(det.html)

My views.py is

```
from django.shortcuts import render

import os
def ser(request):
    return render(request,"ser.html",{});
def det(request):
    return render(request,"det.html",{'name' :name});
```

My urls.py is

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^abt', views.abt),
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^ser',views.ser),
    url(r'^det',views.det),
    ]
```

My det.html has following code

```
<script>

    mounted() {

    var self = this; 

     $.ajax({
                  url: 'post/filter/',
                  data: {
                    category: {{name}},

                  },
                  type: "POST",
                  dataType: 'json',

     success: function (e) { 
      if (e.status == 1) { 
      window.searchContent.vector = e.data;
                    console.log(e);
    }
    }
    });
    </script>
```

I need to pass 'name' to this det.html category in order to fire the ajax request. But when I do this way I am getting error. This is my project using python and vue js. Can anybody please help me?

Error is:

```
missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

Comment: you need to pass data from backend to frontend. See this discussion: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/passing-data-from-a-backend-framework-rails-to-a-vue-component/16324

Comment: I am just using api

Comment: Alright I put an answer together below (your code doesn't pass forward the variable correctly and it is not handled in the backend correctly neither). Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `view.py` file the render has no clue where to get the `name` variable from. Here is one way to fix it: You can pass the `name` parameter from `ser.html` to the backend as GET param:

```
<div>
<a v-bind:href="'searchnew/?name='+post.name">
{{post.name}}</a>
</div>
```

Then in your `view.py` file, get the name variable:

```
def det(request):
    name = request.GET.get('name')
    return render(request,"det.html",{'name' :name})
```

In `det.html` it will be available.

---

If you'd like to do it with POST request, change the ser.html to run a VueJS function, something like this:

```
<div>
<a v-on:click="funcToPost">{{post.name}}</a>
</div>
```

In the VueJS object implement the method funcToPost to do the POST call, something like this:

```
var app = new Vue({
  // ... some code here
  methods: {
    funcToPost: function() {
      // ... some code here
      $.ajax({
        // ... some code here
        data: {
          name: {{name}}
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

In view.py change `request.GET.get('name')` to `request.POST.get('name')`.

Hope this solves your problem. Good luck.

Comment: how can change to a request POST method

Comment: when I use request.POST method is not changing

Comment: @coder I didn't try the solution, there maybe some typos, but the general solution must cover what you want. Best!

Comment: sir, still I have two files.. I need to pass 'name' from ser.html to det,html

Comment: sir, I think you have provide the same to send post request in ser.html

Comment: but i need to send post request from file det.html getting name from ser.html

Comment: @coder I am confused. How do you want to pass the parameter `name` from `ser` to `del`? `del` had been already sending via POST in my first answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159455/discussion-between-coder-and-cmertayak).